# Problem with installing CPLEX Studio 20 on MAC

Tags: installation, cplex

I downloaded "cplex_studio2010-osx" from the website IBM as I need the full version for students and not that demo. After the window for selecting the language opens, everything closes without continuing the installation.
Can you help me solve this problem? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Big Sur or Monterey on your Mac, the issue is probably due to an incompatibility between this version of CPLEX Studio and your Operating System. The fix for BigSur is ready as a beta - please drop a mail to cos-ai-support@wwpdl.vnet.ibm.com with your academic email, and you will get an updated version.